# using django and twisted together

Tags: python, django, chat, twisted, forums

1)I want to devlop a website that has forums and chat.**The chat and forums are linked in some way**.Meaning  for each thread the users can chat in the chat room for that thread or can post a reply to the forum.
I was thinking of using django for forums and twisted for chat thing.Can i combine the two?
The chat application devloped using twisted is linked to the forum.

2)If i use twisted and  django what kind of web host shold i use while putting by website on web ?Shold i use  a VPS? Or can i get a host that supports both?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would not combine the two per se; calls into Django would happen synchronously which means that Twisted's event loop would be blocked. Better to treat the Twisted process as a [standalone app using Django](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/) and to have a classic web server handle the Django app.

You are not likely to find a shared host that will allow you to run a Twisted app, so I would go the VPS route.

Comment: here is a demo of django + hendrix + twisted https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92VeMkjM1TQ

Comment: theres asgi now

Answer (score 10):

I have a project going that might be just what you are looking for (at least to get started).  It is called Hotdot: http://github.com/clemesha/hotdot .

Also, I wrote up more details about this topic here: http://clemesha.org/blog/2009/dec/17/realtime-web-apps-python-django-orbited-twisted/

Comment: this is not maintained anymore

Answer (score 1):

If forum application needs to get something from chat application, it's simplier to make forum application communicate with chat application with plain HTTP requests and to make them run separately.