# Django: communicate with TCP server (with twisted?)

Tags: python, django, tcp, twisted

I have a django application, that needs to talk to a remote TCP server. This server will send packages and depending on what the package is, I need add entries to the database and inform other parts of the application. I also need to actively send requests to the TCP server, for instance when the user navigates to a certain page, I want to subscribe to a certain stream on the TCP server. So communication in both directions need to work.

So far, I use the following solution:

I wrote a custom Django command, that I can start with

```
python manage.py listen
```

This command will start a twisted socket server with `reactor.connectTCP(IP, PORT, factory)` and since it is a django command, I will have access to the database and all the other parts of my application.

But since I also want to be able to send something to the TCP server, triggered by a certain django view, I have an additional socket server, that starts within my twisted application by `reactor.listenTCP(PORT, server_factory)`.

To this server, I will then connect directly in my django application, within a new thread:

```
class MSocket:

    def __init__(self):
        self.stopped = False
        self.socket = None
        self.queue = []
        self.process = start_new_thread(self.__connect__, ())
        atexit.register(self.terminate)


    def terminate(self):
        self.stopped = True
        try:
            self.socket.close()
        except:
            pass

    def __connect__(self):
        if self.stopped:
            return
        attempts = 0
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        while True and not self.stopped:
            try:
                print "Connecting to Socket Server..."
                self.socket.connect(("127.0.0.1", settings.SOCKET_PORT))
                print "Connection Successful!"
                for msg in self.queue:
                    self.socket.send(msg)
                self.queue = []
                break
            except:
                pause = min(int(round(1.2**attempts)), 30)
                print "Connection Failed! Try again in " + str(pause) + " seconds."
                sleep(pause)
                attempts += 1

        self.__loop__()

    def __loop__(self):
        if self.stopped:
            return
        while True and not self.stopped:
            try:
                data = self.socket.recv(1024)
            except:
                try:
                    self.socket.close()
                except:
                    pass
                break
            if not data:
                break
        self.__connect__()

    def send(self, msg):
        try:
            self.socket.send(msg)
            return True
        except:
            self.queue.append(msg)
            return False


m_socket = MSocket()
```

`m_socket` will then be imported by the main `urls.py` so that it starts with django.

So my setup looks kind this:

Sending to TCP Server:

```
Django (connect:8001) ------->  (listen:8001) Twisted (connect:4444) ------> (listen:4444) TCP-Server
```

Receiving from TCP Server

```
TCP-Server (listen:4444) ------> (connect:4444) Twisted ---(direct access)---> Django
```

It all seems to work that way, but I fear that this is not a really good solution, since I have to open this extra TCP connection. So my question would be now, if the setup can be optimized (and I'm sure it can) and how it can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not going to work unless you monkey patch Django (as mentioned by @pss)
I had a similar situation so this is what I did.

1. Run a separate twisted deamon.
2. To communicate from Django to Twisted, use Unix sockets. The local twisted server can listen on Unix sockets (AF_UNIX) and Django can simply connect to that socket. This will avoid going through the TCP stack
3. To communicate from Twisted to Django, you have multiple options,
   a) call Django url with the data
   b) launch a script (Django management command)
   c) Use celery to launch the the above Django command
   d) Use a queue (zeromq or rabbit) and have your Django management command listen in on the queue (preferred)

With the last option, you get much better throughput, durability and it scales well.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I will definitely check this setup out. Wouldn't it be also possible to use the Unix socket to communicate from Twisted to Django? Or would this be a bad idea for some reason?

Comment: You need a listener on the other side on the socket, which would mean that you need to somehow spin a thread inside Django to listen to that socket because it needs to be non blocking. (You could run a another Django command to listen but it is just easier to call Django URL with the data).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using Twisted *within* your Django application.  [Here's an excellent talk about that](http://www.pyvideo.org/video/2597/twisted-mixing), and [a simple example of deploying Django on Twisted](https://github.com/clemesha/twisted-wsgi-django/tree/master), and a [deployment tool for Django that uses Twisted](https://github.com/hangarunderground/hendrix).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand now the problem is how to integrate Twisted into Django app. It does not seem to be a good idea because Twisted's event loop blocks the process.

What you could try is to run Django in non-blocking environment with [gunicorn](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/) and use gevent to implement all communications needed.
If that is not possible - there is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099189/using-django-and-twisted-together) suggesting [standalone Django app](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/) as a way to use Twisted within Django (or rather Django bits inside Twisted).

Personally I would go with gevent. After using Twisted for about 2 years it seems as powerful but old, heavy, hard to learn and hard to debug tool.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately i have no control over the TCP server I'm connecting to.

Comment: Than, I think, design should be driven by the server so you either have to implement servers protocol that will work two-way over single connection or work with two connections if the server can't serve over one.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't specific enough. The problem is not the server or the protocol can not handle two-way communication. The problem is how to integrate this communication in Django. Since the twisted server runs in a different process and, in contrast to Django, non-blocking, it is hard to send a message from inside a Django view.

Comment: I changed the answer. Maybe that will be more helpful.